# Could not understand a output with ++i in C/ C++

Tags: c++, c, printf

While running this I found the output to be: 4 4. Could not understand the cause.

```
int i = 2;
printf("%d %d", ++i, ++i);
```

Comment: A function cannot be called before its arguments are evaluated, can it?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: no, but the values of its arguments can be set in stone before the side-effects of its argument expressions are applied, because the only sequence point in sight is *after* evaluation but *before* the function call. Hence `3 3`, `3 4`, `4 3` and `4 4` are all vaguely plausible outputs for this code, although ofc it has undefined behavior so anything is permitted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have experienced is [Undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Please read about sequence points. Comma is a separator in function calls not an operator.

A sequence point is a point in time at which the dust has settled and all side effects which have been seen so far are guaranteed to be complete. The sequence points listed in the C standard are:

> at the end of the evaluation of a full expression (a full
>   expression is an expression statement, or any other expression which
>   is not a subexpression within any larger expression);
>       at the ||, &&, ?:, and comma operators; and
>       at a function call (after the evaluation of all the arguments, and just before the actual call).

The Standard states that

> Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its
>   stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression.
>   Furthermore, the prior value shall be accessed only to determine the
>   value to be stored.